# How to group-center / standardize variables in R?

Tags: r, standardization, centering

Functions I'm familiar with include [scale](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/scale.html) from base R, [rescale](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/arm/html/rescale.html) from ARM.

Perhaps the best way would be to use some variant of apply, specifying one or more variables to use as grouping variables.

Comment: Try:
aggregate(state.x77, list(Region = state.region,  Cold = state.x77[,"Frost"] > 130)), function(x) ((x - mean(x))/sd(x)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possible [plyr](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) solution. Note that it relies on the base `transform()` function.

```
my.df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, mean=10), 
                    sex=sample(c("M","F"), 100, rep=T), 
                    group=gl(5, 20, labels=LETTERS[1:5]))
library(plyr)
ddply(my.df, c("sex", "group"), transform, x.std = scale(x))
```

(We can check whether it works as expected with e.g., `with(subset(my.df, sex=="F" & group=="A"), scale(x))`)

Basically, the 2nd argument describes how to "split" the data, the 3rd argument what function to apply to each chunk. The above will append a variable `x.std` to the data.frame. Use `x` if you want to replace your original variable by the scaled one.

Answer (score 7):

```
group.center <- function(var,grp) {
    return(var-tapply(var,grp,mean,na.rm=T)[grp])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) solution.  It is definitely faster than plyr (relevant only for large data sets).  Maybe later I'll do up a dplyr example.

```
# generate example data
raw.data <- data.frame( outcome = c(rnorm(500, 100, 15), rnorm(500, 110, 12)), 
                        group = c(rep("a", 500), rep("b", 500)))

library(data.table)
# convert dataframe to data.table
raw.data <- data.table(raw.data, key = "group")

# create group standardized outcome variable
raw.data[ , group_std_outcome := (outcome - mean(outcome, na.rm = TRUE)) /  
           sd(outcome, na.rm = TRUE), "group"]
```

(Yes, I rediscovered a question I asked years ago when I was an R noob ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use (among others) `tapply` for this (the `plyr` package contains lots of other options that may be better suited for your specific situation):

```
tapply(variabletoscale, list(groupvar1, groupvar2), scale)
```

Comment: With two factors, it won't return a data.frame. You'll need to post-process the result for that.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from a [white paper](http://www.ne.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.216115.1426234213!/menu/standard/file/clustering1.pdf) by Mahmood Arai. It has the convenient side effect of labeling the centered results with the prefix "C.":

```
gcenter <- function(df1,group) {
        variables <- paste(
              rep("C", ncol(df1)),  colnames(df1), sep=".")
        copydf <- df1
        for (i in 1:ncol(df1)) {
              copydf[,i] <- df1[,i] - ave(df1[,i], group, FUN=mean)}
        colnames(copydf) <- variables
        return(cbind(df1,copydf))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated implementation using **dplyr** from **tidyverse**.

```
library(tidyverse)

my.df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100, mean=10), sex=sample(c("M","F"), 100, rep=T))
my.df <- group_by(my.df, sex) %>% mutate(x.sd = as.numeric(scale(x)))
```